How can I properly exclude Identity tables in .NET 8?
I'm trying to exclude some tables that come by default with Identity, but I get this warning for each of them:
The entity type 'IdentityUserToken' was first mapped explicitly and then ignored. Consider not mapping the entity type in the first place.

This is my program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("APIContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'APIContextConnection' not found.");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<APIContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<APIUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<APIContext>();

// Add services to the container.
ServiceContainer.AddServices(builder.Services);
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISeeder, Seeder>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Configure JWT authentication
var key = builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
    throw new InvalidOperationException("JWT key not found.");

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key))
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
}

Seed();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

void Seed()
{
    using var scope = app.Services.CreateScope();
    var dbSeeder = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISeeder>();
    dbSeeder.Seed();
}

And this is my context:
public class APIContext(DbContextOptions<APIContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<APIUser>(options)
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<APIUser>().ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserToken<string>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>();
    }

    // Entities
    public DbSet<APIUser> User { get; set; }
}

I've tried to put the base.OnModelCreating(builder); below all the builder.Ignore<> but it didn't work.
I don't really get any errors, but every time I run a migration I get this warnings and it's very annoying :D

According to your warning that indicates that you're first mapping the IdentityUserToken, IdentityUserClaim, IdentityUserLogin, and IdentityRoleClaim entities explicitly and then ignoring them. The warning suggests that instead of mapping them explicitly and then ignoring them, you should consider not mapping them in the first place. Becasue, The key is to not call base.OnModelCreating(builder) before excluding the unwanted tables. This prevents warning. So to fix this issue, just reverse the order first write the ignore then the user, role and userrole.

It didn't work. Neither adding base.OnModelCreating(builder); at the end nor at the beginning

You should get rid of base.OnModelCreating because base.OnModelCreating(builder) call from IdentityDbContext might still be implicitly configuring the Identity tables even if you place it after your Ignore statements in OnModelCreating

But if I delete it, i get this error:
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The entity type 'IdentityUserRole' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

What's your APIUser details looks like?

As I'm trying to make a kind of "template API" I didn't add any extra property, so it looks like this:
`public class APIUser : IdentityUser
{
}
`

Note: I've fixed it by inheriting my context from DbContext, not from IdentityDbContext.
This is the result:
public class APIContext(DbContextOptions<APIContext> options) : DbContext(options)
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserToken<string>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim<string>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();
        builder.Ignore<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>();
        
        builder.Entity<APIUser>()
            .ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .ToTable("Role");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
            .ToTable("UserRole")
            .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
    }

    // Entities
    public DbSet<APIUser> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityRole> Role { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdentityUserRole<string>> UserRole { get; set; }
}

